# How to configure a CustomBinding to use a CustomMessageEncoder in a config file

Tags: c#, wcf, configuration, web-config

I have a CustomBinding and a CustomMessageEncoder, CustomMessageEncoderFactory and a CustomMessageEncodingBindingElement.

I want my CustomBinding to use this CustomMessageEncoder.

But how can I configure this in my config file?

Thanks,

Michiel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can configure your CustomBinding and Encoder, within the configuration element of your web.config, like so:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <customBinding>
        <binding name="CustomBindingWithCustomMessageEncoder">
          <CustomMessageEncoder />
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
    </bindings>
    <extensions>
      <bindingElementExtensions>
        <add name="CustomMessageEncoder" type="Full.NameSpace.To.CustomMessageEncoderBindingElementExtension, Assembly.CustomMessageEncoder.Lives.In, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xyz" />
      </bindingElementExtensions>
    </extensions>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I had to create the "CustomMessageEncoderBindingElementExtension".

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer and config example.  Unfortunately, even with that level of detail, MS made this so confusing that it still took me half a day to figure out how to make the rest of the [custom binding configuration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731377) (other than the custom encoder - ie. transport config) match the configuration I was using with the original [basicHttpBinding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731361).  I've detailed the entire process [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39502619/1801144) for anyone looking for an even more detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what you want here. Are you referring to how to make your own custom binding that can be configured through the config file, or how to use a CustomBinding in a config file?

If it's the latter, the WCF docs explain pretty well what you need: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731377.aspx